# Why no relaxing of all edges in the first iteration of Bellman Ford Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

Please refer to the following page for Bellman ford algorithm (it shows an e.g). 
http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/11/29/one-source-shortest-path-the-bellman-ford-algorithm

I still don’t get it. In the first loop iteration of the outer loop, let’s say by the example, u first modify edge 1->2 and edge 1->4, what’s the problem in relaxing the edge 2->3, 2->5, 4->3, 4->5,in the same step, since we have d[2] and d[4].

Comment: There isn't a problem. You can do that, and in fact the code you linked does that (or can, depending on the order in which the edges appear in the input file). You've just chosen a particular order for relaxing edges that results in a happy outcome. In the linked post, all edges are checked each time through the relaxation step and the distances updated as each edge is relaxed, so it's conceivable for a particular graph that all edges will be fully relaxed at the end of the first relaxation iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This problem magically disappears if you use a sligtly different version of Bellman-Ford:

```
set toRelax = {initial_vertex}
while toRelax is not empty:
    u = remove a vertex from toRelax
    for each neighbour v of u:
       if we can relax u-v:
          relax u-v
          add v to toRelax
```

Notice how each "step" now involves a single vertex! Things being done in the "same step" or not are just an artifact of the specific implementation you use and don't really change the algorithm in the end.

Comment: I really like this version. You're only trying to relax edges that have a chance to change the current state. Is there something in the literature about this approach? Is it really still B-F? It seems like an iterative Dijkstra's, where instead of optimizing a vertex in one step you just get it as good as it can get in that step, while retaining the right to revisit it in the future.

Comment: But it seems this approach loses the ability to detect negative cycles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817131/bellman-ford-queue-based-approach-from-sedgewick-and-wayne-algorithms-4th-edi?rq=1