# Bellman ford queue based approach from Sedgewick and Wayne - Algorithms, 4th edition

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I was studying `queue-based` approach for `Bellman-Ford algorithm`for single source shortest path from `Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne - Algorithms, 4th edition` 
source code for algorithm from book is present at this link http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/BellmanFordSP.java.

I have two points one is a doubt and other is code improvement suggestion.

1. In above approach following is code for relax method for relaxing distance to vertices.

   ```
   for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v)) {
       int w = e.to();
       if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight()) {
           distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight();
           edgeTo[w] = e;
           if (!onQueue[w]) {
               queue.enqueue(w);
               onQueue[w] = true;
           }
       }
       if (cost++ % G.V() == 0){
           findNegativeCycle();
       }
   }
   ```

In this method below condition is used before finding negative cycle.

```
if (cost++ % G.V() == 0){
     findNegativeCycle();
}
```

Above they are dividing cost by number of `vertices` in graph to check for `negative cycle`. It may be because 
relaxation is done `V-1` times and if relaxation run for `Vth` time it means it has cycle, where V is number of vertices.

But I think in queue-based approach they are using divisor to check at regular interval if cycle has occurred or not. A cycle can occur 
before or just after above condition is true. If cycle occurred after above condition is true then algorithm has to wait till next time condition is 
true to detect cycle, it is not necessary that cycle will occur exactly when if `(cost++ % G.V() == 0)` is true. So I think divisor can be any number small enough so that we can check for cycle after appropriate time interval.
Am I right in thinking that?

2. The code improvement suggestion is that `findNegativeCycle()` method can be used to return true if cycle has occurred. Thus. this condition-

   `if (cost++ % G.V() == 0) { findNegativeCycle(); }`

Can be changed to-

```
if (cost++ % G.V() == 0)
    if(findNegativeCycle()){
        return;
    }
```

In code for loop keeps on running even if `findNegativeCycle()` method has found a cycle. So we can return if cycle has occurred instead of processing rest of for loop.

Please share your thoughts for above 2 points.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are right. In their [online materials](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/), authors explain that they check every Vth call in order to amortize the cost of building the associated edge-weighted digraph and finding the cycle in it:

> Accordingly, to implement negativeCycle() BellmanFordSP.java builds an
>   edge-weighted digraph from the edges in edgeTo[] and looks for a cycle
>   in that digraph. To find the cycle, it uses
>   EdgeWeightedDirectedCycle.java, a version of DirectedCycle.java from
>   Section 4.3, adapted to work for edge-weighted digraphs. **We amortize
>   the cost of this check by performing this check only after every Vth
>   call to relax()**.

In other words, you can check more often, but then you risk performance loss.

2. Again, you are right. The existence of the negative cycle is currently checked in `while` loop in the constructor. However, in the worst case the `relax` method can detect the cycle by checking first edge in the `for` loop, and instead of exiting it will continue and check other edges (max `V-2` of them). With your suggested improvement that can save significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Very happy to see the answers by Miljen Mikic. It really helps to understand the algorithm. However, I still have another question. In the text, it says "To complete the implementation, we need to ensure that the algorithm terminates
after V passes. One way to achieve this end is to explicitly keep track of the passes." Here, I believe the variable "cost" is the count of the passes, but shouldn't the lines

```
if (cost++ % G.V() == 0)
    findNegativeCycle();
```

be at least outside of the for loop? Like

```
private void relax(EdgeWeightedDigraph G, int v)
    {
        for (DirectedEdge e : G.adj(v)
             {
                  int w = e.to();
                  if (distTo[w] > distTo[v] + e.weight())
                       {
                           distTo[w] = distTo[v] + e.weight();
                           edgeTo[w] = e;
                           if (!onQ[w])
                                 {
                                      q.enqueue(w);
                                      onQ[w] = true;
                                 }
                        }
              }
         if (cost++ % G.V() == 0)
              findNegativeCycle();
      }
```

Actually even it's outside of the for loop, it's not the best solution, as during each pass, there could be multiple vertices to be relaxed. So it could be designed better in the constructor of BellmanFordSP by remembering how many vertices to be relaxed during each pass. Am I correct? Thanks!

Comment: cost is supposed to be the number of calls to relax() instead of the number of passes (please see the comment for cost in page 674). In this case I believe it is better to put the if condition outside of the for loop as you suggested. What you described is one way to implement the algorithm but it was not the one implemented in the book (please see page 673 "Our implementation BellmanFordSP uses a different approach"). In summary, there are two ways to implement queue-based algorithm: 1. terminate after V passes as you described; 2. terminate when queue is empty or a negative cycle is found